# Separate schema & Shared database multi-tenant strategy in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, multi-tenant, saas

I have a Django backend. Right now, I'm developing with sqlite3 and on deployment I'm planning to use postgresql.

I have an invoicing app, with each tenant having at least (as of now) the following models:

```
Manufacturer, Product (each product to have foreign key relation to manufacturer), 
Zone , Customer (each customer to have foreign key relation to zone),
Purchase invoice and Sales invoice.
```

Now, my question is how is multi tenancy with separate schemas and same database approached in django & (sqlite3 or postgresql). I could not find much tutorials on that as well. So, how should I go about with this thing?

Comment: https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ this might help

Comment: thanks a lot RA 123!! I'm going through it!! I would like to know how this works? Like how does the separation works on the database level?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used it yet, so i don't exactly know how it works.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I am dealing with something similar where I can't figure out the best approach to writing migrations in a dev environment using sqlite3, then moving it into the production environment using tenant_schemas / postgres.